# Getting Session in facebook

Tags: facebook, session, key

Can we get session key in Facebook in below mentioned scenario? Through my app, I called facebook login, dialog appeared:

1. I logged in Facebook then second dialog for permissions appear
2. I denied permissions for accessing some user information by pressing deny.I called Fb.logout but it gives me error "logout called without session", but if open a new tab and type www.facebook.com it shows me logged in.

So, I was wondering that session has to exist but I do not know how to get that?

can somebody please help or guide or correct me, if wrong.

Thanks and Regards,
Prashant Verma

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: You can only log out a user that is connected to your site.

refer: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.logout/

The user does get logged-in to Facebook but not authorized your application. Your app does not hold the session, and it can't log-out the user.

Comment: Is there no way to get this thing done because if my app is running on internet in public place and somebody does this and leave then next user when opens the facebook will be able to access the profile of previous user. Isn't this wrong ?

Comment: @P.V In a way, I agree you. Normally, a user wouldn't think that he has logged in to Facebook when he disallows your app. But FB does not give your app any control over users session if he does not permit your app. You first login to FB, then validate the app -- is the flow.

Comment: Thanks Nishant.. I think both the steps create the Login process.